# Running a procedure from the IDE goes, while if a trigger calls it goes wrong

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012, procedure

I have created a trigger, it will run when the user change the document status. The SQL version where I worked is the 15.0.2000.5 and everything goes right. Instead, the customer has the 12.0.4100.1 and the trigger give me some error with the procedure.
The procedure scope is to create a new line in the current document. When the trigger run the procedure insert the new line but some fields are not correctly compiled and in the software, used from the customer, these new lines I can't see.

I try the procedure without the trigger and does its job. I try the trigger code in my IDE and perform correctly its tasks.
I have try to debug saving some data in temporary table to see input and output result but they seem correct.
I thought it was a permission issued but I have created and run this one with the same user, however I try this piece of code:

```
BEGIN TRY
  EXEC(N'
    USE [master];
    GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO [administrator];
');
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  DECLARE @DoNothing INT;
END CATCH;
```

Anyone can say me other issues? Maybe the SQL version doesn't allow some features?

If you need me code.
This is the trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER <trigger name> ON <document table>
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- control status changed
    IF UPDATE(Status)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @optionCode VARCHAR(6) = 'TRPREV'
        DECLARE @documentsType VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @released VARCHAR(4) = '001'
        DECLARE @notReleased VARCHAR(4) = '002'
        DECLARE @documentIndex INT
        DECLARE @newStatus VARCHAR(4)

        -- get all the orders code
        SET @documentsType = (SELECT TOP 1 ValueOption FROM Options WHERE OP_Cle = @optionCode)

        SELECT @doCpt = DO_Cpt, @newStatus = DO_Status
        FROM inserted
        INNER JOIN TypeDoc TD ON TD.TD_Code = DO_TypeDoc AND CHARINDEX(TD_Code, @documentsType) > 0
        
        -- delete the previsionelle
        IF ( @newStatus = @notReleased )
        BEGIN
            -- delete some lines

        END 
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- create the previsionelle
            IF ( @newStatus = @released OR ISNULL(@newStatus, '') = '' )
            BEGIN
                EXEC crea_previsionali @doCpt
            END 
        END
    END -- update if

GO
```

This is the procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <procedure name>
    @DoCpt AS INT
AS
    -- declared some variables

    DECLARE @Cursor as CURSOR;

    -- preare the cursors
    SET @Cursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Cpt,TypeDoc,ItemType,DateEch,PrixHT,PrixHTMB,ShipToAddressType,MarginUC_Base 
    FROM Lignes 
    WHERE DOCpt=@DoCpt
      AND Previsionnelle=0
    ORDER BY DOCpt,No
     
    OPEN @Cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @T_LiCpt,@T_TypeDoc,@T_ItemType,@T_DateEch,@T_PrixHT,@T_PrixHTMB,@T_ShipToAddressType,@T_MarginUC_Base;
 
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
                    IF EXISTS (SELECT GR_Pere AS C FROM vw_GrammaireIT WITH(NOLOCK) 
                               WHERE (GR_Type = 0) 
                                   AND (GR_Prev = 1) 
                                     AND (GR_Fils = @T_TypeDoc) 
                                     AND (ItemType = @T_ItemType))
                BEGIN

                    PRINT cast(@T_Cpt as VARCHAR (50))

                    SELECT @PROV_TD_Code=TD_Code, @PROV_TD_TypePrix=TD_TypePrix, @PROV_TD_ImpStock=ISNULL(TD_ImpStock, 0)
                    , @PROV_TD_reliquat=ISNULL(TD_Reliquat, 0), @PROV_TD_Transfer=ISNULL(TD_Transfer, 0) 
                    FROM vw_GrammaireIT WITH(NOLOCK) 
                    INNER JOIN TypeDoc WITH(NOLOCK) ON Pere=Code
                    WHERE Fils=@T_TypeDoc and Prev=1  AND ItemType=@T_ItemType

                    exec sp_CreateProvisional @T_LI_DateEch
                                                                        ,@T_PrixHTMB
                                                                        ,@T_PrixHT
                                                                        ,@T_ShipToAddressType
                                                                        ,@prov
                                                                        ,@PROV_TD_Code
                                                                        ,@PROV_TD_ImpStock
                                                                        ,1
                                                                        ,@T_LiCpt
                                                                        ,@T_MarginUC_Base
                                                                        ,@PROV_TD_reliquat

                END

            FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @T_LiCpt,@T_TypeDoc,@T_ItemType,@T_DateEch,@T_PrixHT,@T_PrixHTMB,@T_ShipToAddressType,@T_MarginUC_Base;
 
    CLOSE @Cursor;
    DEALLOCATE @Cursor;
GO
```

Comment: Careful, that `TRIGGER` appears to assume a DML operation only effects one row; that is simply not true.

Comment: Also, why are you using a `CURSOR` here (SQL is a set based language) *and* `NOLOCK` (you understand the implications of such a query hint, correct)? That looks like some design flaws there if I am honest. The `sp_` prefix is also **reserved** by Microsoft and means **S**pecial **P**rocedure; it should not be used for user objects.

Comment: This procedure 'sp_CreateProvisional' was present by default in the customer's software.